# Sequelize have a limit of return 1000 rows of my table - oracle connection

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a table which have 4750 rows, however, when I use findAndCountAll() it always returns 1000 rows even I set limit with 2200 rows. I'm using Sequelize with a Oracle DB.

There is a  configuration to allow me return whole 4750 rows with only 1 request?

Request GET in my API

```
const { count, rows } = await User.findAndCountAll({
        offset: 1,
        raw: true,
        limit: 2200,
        subQuery:false
      });
```

response JSON I get from findAndCountAll

```
{
    "count": 4750,
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": "10003734",
            "name": "LUIS"
        },
        {
            "id": "10003735",
            "name": "PEDRO"
        },
        {
            "id": "10003736",
            "name": "CARLOS"
        }}
     ....997 rows more
   ]
}
```

Comment: Do you get all 4750 rows if you remove `limit` and `offset` options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sequelize, the maxRows option default to 1000 unless it is set. You can get the sequelize instance that would return more than 1000 rows by setting the maxRows option when getting a Sequelize instance.

You can get the Sequelize instance as I have shown below and then do the findAndCountAll call.

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConfig.serviceName, dbConfig.user, 
                   dbConfig.password,{host: dbConfig.host, port: 
                   dbConfig.port, dialect: 'oracle', dialectOptions: {maxRows: 2500}});
```

Comment: Thanks, the important part was `dialectOptions: {maxRows: 2500}`. It works good!

Comment: @KevinMontañezHuamán Nilabja will look at removing the limit.  And you may be interested in his post https://medium.com/oracledevs/node-js-sequelize-with-oracle-database-its-official-dbbad242ff4c

Comment: @KevinMontañezHuamán You can use the latest version of sequelize v6 where I have fixed this limitation.

Comment: For future readers, that version is 6.25.8